# boostrap sidebar button gets invisible when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to use boostrap sidebar in my asp.net MVC application ,I am using a button(#menu-toggle) on side of sidebar  which will toggle sidebar .everthing is fine but when I resize the screen the button vanishes.I want the button to be visible on all screens .usually I am putting left to button so that it matches with the width of sidebar.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
        </li>
        @Html.Action("Reports", "Dashboard")
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="body">@RenderBody()</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu-toggle {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 10px;
}

#menu-toggle.toggled {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 260px;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}

@@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #menu-toggle {
    display:block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #menu-toggle.toggled {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 260px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-toggle {
    display:block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #menu-toggle.toggled {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 260px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu-toggle", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: I can't see `#menu-toggle` in HTML, If possible create working snippet.

Comment: yes add your working sample link

Comment: I am developing in asp.net mvc. issue is #menu-toggle  button vanishes after screen resize ..pls help  I am refering following link     http://www.bootply.com/dragan/3AZB0lGFyt

Comment: well, your css is different from the bootply one, it's definitely your css, try build one like the bootply one you provided, and link it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@media` instead of `@@media` and you can use percentage value for `top` in `#menu-toggle`

```js
$(document).on("click", "#menu-toggle", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
#menu-toggle {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 10px;
}

#menu-toggle.toggled {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 260px;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #menu-toggle {
    display:block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #menu-toggle.toggled {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 260px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-toggle {
    display:block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #menu-toggle.toggled {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 260px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#menu-toggle" style="background-color:gray" id="menu-toggle">></a>
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
        </li>
        @Html.Action("Reports", "Dashboard")
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="body">@RenderBody()</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ..it got me in right direction  ..we cant put single @ in asp.net mvc